# WSO2 EMM Supported Android Devices

Tags: android, wso2

I am trying to add a `gotab` android table to our new install of `WSO2 EMM` but when I browse to the enrollment site I get the following message:

> "This device cannot access EMM"

Why would this be? what are the supported Android versions? This device is running 4.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically,  they support all non-rooted Android devices. But the Vendor Name field of the EMM-DB's DEVICES Table is too short, they declared it as Varchar(11) so even if the agent code runs correctly, the server does not accept the return result from the agent. This might be the case.

You can check it from the servers console. Or you can try it with another Android Device. Also it would be beneficial to check the return String of the

`Build.MANUFACTURER;`

from the Android device.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 EMM Supports non-rooted devices which has the OS version Android OS 4.1 or above.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen when EMM unable to understand you are accessing from an Android device. Most probably your device is not sending the correct User Agent value to the EMM. You can edit that value in /emm/api/deviceRouter.js